# Controls in flyout lose interaction upon opening a second time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a few mahapps flyouts that are used for user input, I bind them like so:

```
<Controls:Flyout Header="New/Edit Program" Width="500" x:Name="newProgramFlyout"
                 IsOpen="{Binding EditProgramOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and then I have a toolbar button that opens it by setting "EditProgramOpen" to true and raising property changed. This works well.

The problem arises when I submit the data in the flyout, I close it, and on subsequent opens, the forms lose a lot of interactive space. Certain text boxes I can only focus by clicking in a very small area or by tabbing to them, some comboboxes become completely unclickable so I have to tab them, etc.

This does not happen when I open it, don't submit, close it, and reopen it so I believe the problem lies in how I'm closing it?  Here's how my code closes the flyout:

```
private void _closeEditProgramFlyout()
{
    EditProgramOpen = false;
    RaisePropertyChanged("EditProgramOpen");
}
```

Fairly uneventful, not sure what is going wrong. It's almost as if something is on top of the controls, but not visible.

IMPORTANT INFO EDIT: I just noticed, whenever this issue occurs, the interactive space on each control in the flyout is limited to what seems like the left 1/3 of the flyout space -- if the control starts after that, it's completely unclickable, if it spans that, I can't click beyond that point. Odd.